# Which Scriptures describe "Vish Purush" who incarnated as Aswatthama?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, scripture

Some [blogs](http://aishwarya-ananth.blogspot.in/2014/07/ashwatthama-chiranjeevi-mahabharata.html) on internet claim that,

> During Samudra Manthanam, Halahaal the fuming posion capable of burning
>   universe appeared and all Dev Danav Manav Yaksha Gandharva fled. All
>   of them along with Lord Vishnu and Lord Bramha came to Lord Shiva.
>   Lord Shiva consumed Halahaal and held it in his throat. However unable
>   to bear its consequences it started burning him. The **Vish purush**
>   sprung out of Him. Lord Shiva told him, " Although we (lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva) didn’t let you kill the people, yet in
>   Dwapar Yuga during Mahabharat war with my blessings you will be able
>   to kill oppressive kshatriyas. Later you will assume the post of
>   Saptarishis in following Manvantara. You will be born as Bhardwaja’s
>   grandson and be raised as Brahman but attracted towards Kshatriyahood ".

Which Scriptures describe springing out **"Vish Purusha"** from throat of Lord Rudra aka Shiva? Are there any scriptures which prophesied the birth of Aswatthama other than Mahabhartha?

Comment: The Adi Parva of the Mahabharata says Ashatthama was "born... of the united portions of Mahadeva, Yama, Kama, and Krodha." http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm Perhaps the embodiment of the poison is being equated with either Yama god of death, Kama god of desire, or Krodha god of anger.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It is generally said Lord Shiva (destroyer) in Aswathama killed Upapandavas and Aswathama was relieved from curse later by praying to Adi Para Shakti. So, i need to know official scriptures where  Vish Purusha is mentioned.

Comment: That Asvathama is a partial incarnation of Rudra is a fact mentioned in Devi Bhagavatam.